# Problema con Login password_verify me sale siempre sesion no iniciada

Tags: php, html5, php7

se que hay muchos hilos de esto pero cada código es distinto, el mio es muy simple, llamo a las funciones correspondientes, tengo un if y else, en el if verifico las contraseña y devuelvo una alert que me dice sesión iniciada y en el else un alert que me dice sesión iniciada, lo que no sé es que por más que ponga la contraseña y el correo correctamente me salta la alerte del else, este es mi código de logi:

```
  $mail = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['mail']));
    $pass = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['pass']));

    if (!empty($_POST["ing"]))
    {

        include('conectardb.php');

        session_start();
        $con = conectar();
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",  $mail);
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (password_verify($pass, $row['password']))
        {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION["authorized"]= true;
            $_SESSION["sess_name"]= $row['user'];
            $_SESSION["sess_email"]= $row['email'];
            $_SESSION["sess_password"]= $row['password'];
            session_write_close();
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sesion iniciada');</script>";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Sesion no iniciada');</script>";
        }
    }
```

Este es conectardb.php:

```
<?php 
    function conectar()
    {
        $user = "root"; 
        $pass = ""; 
        $server = "localhost"; 
        $db = "Tripex";
        $con = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db) or die ("Error al conectar" .mysql_error());
        return $con;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Consejos:
- Comprueba que el aloritmo de encriptación utilizado en password_hash ha sido el mismo.
- Comprueba que en la DB, el campo en cuestión tiene longitud suficiente para almacenar el hash.
- Haz un print_r de ambos valores y compara.

Answer (score 1):

varias cosas.

Estás modificando la contraseña original. htmlentities y addslashes modificarán el contenido de esa variable. Mira este ejemplo:

```
$pass = 'zho\la<!';
echo htmlentities(addslashes($pass));
zho\\la&lt;!
```

Quizás intentas hacer satinize. Para eso hay esto:

```
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Tienes más información sobre eso aquí: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input-array.php

Después en el query de SQL estás usando "?" para determinar tu argumento pero estás asociando "s". ¿Has visto lo que devuelve $row['password'] antes de hacer el if? Prueba con

```
print_r($row);
```

antes del if a ver qué se ve. Seguramente tendrás que hacer algo así:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->bind_param(":email",  $mail);
```

Prueba y a ver qué te dice.

Comment: Cuando cambie:
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email");
$stmt->bind_param(":email",  $mail); 
Me salió Esto:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

Comment: Desconozco qué es bind_param. Pensé que era una función tuya. La de pdo se llama bindParam()

Comment: Con el tema del satinize me ayudo, logré conseguirlo

Answer (score 1):

El problema, aparte del filtro satinize, estaba esto:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Lo tuve que sacar y cambiarlo de esta manera:

```
    $stmt->bind_param("s",  $mail);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $myrow = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Y todo solucionado, gracias